# 'undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass in ruby

Tags: ruby

This is my code for converting a user entered string into a Caesar cipher.

```
puts "text?"
text = gets.chomp

puts "key?"
key = gets.chomp.to_i 

plainTex = Array.new 
ciphTex = Array.new

j = 0 

text.each_byte do |i|
  plainTex[j] = i
  j += 1
end

j = 0 

plainTex.each_entry do |i|

  if ( i == 32 )
    ciphTex[j] = plainTex[j]
    j += 1
    end

  if( plainTex[j] > 64) and (plainTex[j] < 91 )
    if( (plainTex[j] + key) > 91)
      ciphTex[j] = (plainTex[j] + key ) - 90
      j += 1
    else 
      ciphTex[j] = plainTex[j] + key 
      j += 1 
    end
  end

  if( plainTex[j] > 94) and (plainTex[j] < 123)
    if( (plainTex [j] + key) > 122)
      ciphTex [j] = (plainTex[j] + key) - 122
      j += 1 
    else 
      ciphTex[j] = plainTex[j] + key
      j += 1
    end
  end
 end 

ciphTex.each_entry do |i|
  puts i
end
```

now, I'm getting error :
 **undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)**

Search on the web led me to conclude that plainTex might be nil,as the error message is saying( which should not be the case as *plainTex* is fed data beforehand).

**On a side note** : the program runs fine when the input string *is  all lowercase and has no space.* I don't know why.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: good place to start would be to note the line number in the error, that will help narrow it down.

Comment: line 26 :   if( plainTex[j] > 64) and (plainTex[j] < 91 )                               couldn't make anything of it.

Comment: The object that you are calling `>` is `nil`. What object are you calling `>` on? Hint: it's **not** `plainTex`.

Comment: it's not the  `j'th` element of `plaintex`? because there is the comparison of `plainTex[j]  > 64`

Comment: @arun-that-plays-chess `plaintex[j]` may be nil. a debugger might help

Comment: nope, `plaintex[j]` stores the ASCII values. I just checked by adding a loop to print the contents of `plainTex` (before the comparison in line 26) and it printed ASCII value.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem Explained

When you access array with index that is out of bounds you'll get no error, but result `nil`.

```
irb --simple-prompt
>> a = [1]
=> [1]
>> a[0]
=> 1
>> a[1]
=> nil
>> a[200]
=> nil
```

### Debugging your code

A little bit of puts statements reveal the issue:

```
text.each_byte do |i|
  plainTex[j] = i
  j += 1
end

j = 0 

puts "Length: #{plainTex.length}"

plainTex.each_entry do |i|

  if ( i == 32 )
    ciphTex[j] = plainTex[j]
    j += 1
  end
  puts "j: #{j}"
```

This is the output

```
text?
Testing Test
key?
32
Length: 12
j: 0
j: 2
j: 3
j: 4
j: 5
j: 6
j: 7
j: 8
j: 10
j: 11
j: 12
test.rb:30:in `block in <main>': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:23:in `each'
    from test.rb:23:in `each_entry'
    from test.rb:23:in `<main>
```

Last index of array in this case was 11 and you accessed index 12.
You got result `nil` then you tried to call method `>` on nil.

### Professional debugging

You can install gem `pry-byebug` and use short aliases `s`, `n` for step into, next etc.

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug

### Bug Found

Using `pry-byebug` it's immediatelly clear what's the bug, even though I don't really understand your code because those numbers are meaningless to me.

For first letter it increments `j` in second condition `if( plainTex[j] > 64) and (plainTex[j] < 91 )`. Then with incremented `j` it moves to `if( plainTex[j] > 94) and (plainTex[j] < 123)` where it increments it again.

You should use `elsif` for all of these or `next`

### Code Cleanup

Ruby convention is to use snake case to name your variable and I'd change this piece of code:

```
if( plainTex[j] > 64) and (plainTex[j] < 91 )
  if( (plainTex[j] + key) > 91)
    ciphTex[j] = (plainTex[j] + key ) - 90
    j += 1
  else 
    ciphTex[j] = plainTex[j] + key 
    j += 1 
  end
end
```

to this:

```
if plain_text[j].between?(65, 90)
  ciph_text[j] = plain_text[j] + key
  ciph_text[j] -= 90 if ciph_text[j] > 91
  j += 1
end
```

It seems that you are repeating j += 1 in every condition, so why not remove it outside if/else blocks and put it as last line before the loop `end`?

Also I am a human and I don't want to remember that "A" is 65 and "Z" is 90. Why not say so in the code?

```
if plain_text[j].between?("A".ord, "Z".ord)
```

I have never messed with ASCII in ruby, but I am sure you could further improve this, possibly do entire cypher in one simple loop with 10 lines of code or less.

Ruby is really good at processing arrays, so use that. I'd do something like this:

```
plain_text = text.codepoints
cyph_text = plain_text.map do |code|
  if code == ' '.ord
    ' '.ord
  elsif
    # return cypher code
  end
end
```

Check out how map function works.

Comment: Um..but why is the value of j iterating from 0 to 2? The iteration statement clearly states `j += 1`; the whole reason that  `plainTex[j] ` goes nil is because of that. I can't seem to get that around my head.

Comment: Why don't you start this file with `require 'pry-byebug'` and put line `binding.pry` in your loop and then step through it yourself by pressing `s` <Enter> (or full word `step` if you don't setup aliases?

Comment: Those numbers are **ASCII codes**. If `j` gets incremented  for both the `if` conditions, why would it not happen for the next iteration of the loop? But yeah, I should use a  debugger. I just thought the error was something trivial. And yes the code can be a mess maybe for you, but that doesn't mean I don't know how to ask a question. Does it?  Thanks anyway.

Comment: And you did ask a good question, I have upvoted it yesterday or before. Also I have provided some suggestions on how to clean up the code

Comment: @arun-that-plays-chess - I have provided some suggestions on how to improve the code. It's fine to do it your own way especially if you are just learning new language.